# Can someone help me understand this proof: there exists a complement of an RE language is not RE

Tags: computability, turing-machines, proof-techniques

I'm trying to understand this proof in Peter Linz's [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=hsxDiWvVdBcC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=%22there%20exists%20a%20recursively%20enumerable%20language%20whose%20complement%20is%20not%20recursively%20enumerable%22&source=bl&ots=rdMsPjVsaS&sig=Ja23eh7yEIUwZh1W1KPxdMAsdSs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNlNLnpqnTAhVIwVQKHWA6Ag0Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22there%20exists%20a%20recursively%20enumerable%20language%20whose%20complement%20is%20not%20recursively%20enumerable%22&f=false)

The math just doesn't make any sense, I don't understand how this is a proof. First of all, the author says let's define a language such that:

for all i>0: a^i ∈ L(Mi)

That seems ok. Then he says let's consider the complement of L.

L'={a^i:a^i ∉ L(Mi)}.

How is this even possible? The author just stated a statement that is in itself a paradox. The set of turing machines is countable and for all "i" there is a corresponding machine; so how can we say later that for some a^i there is no turing machine? And isn't the complement going to be the empty set anyway? But the author keeps going and deduces a contradiction, I understand that part, but isn't the contradiction a result of what seems to me a paradoxical statement in the first place?

The way I understand it's like saying:

---

For all fruits, there exists a tree that produces a specific one.

An apple is a fruit. Let a be an apple and define A to be the set of all apples and T(Ai) be the tree that produces a specific apple.

Now define A' to be the set of all apples that don't have a corresponding tree T(Ai).

Assume A' to be a set of fruits, then there must exists a corresponding tree T(Ak) for all elements. (**)

Consider a^k. Is it in A or in A'?

if it is in A', then a ∉ A' a contradiction. by (**)

if it is in A, then a ∈ A , but also a ∉ T(Ak) which means it is in A'. A contradiction.

We get contradiction either way so A' isn't a set of fruits.

---

I put this example to illustrate my point. What went wrong in the apples example is that I defined a set to have apples that don't have corresponding trees, even though I stated before that all apples have corresponding trees since they're all fruits. Thus, if anything, A' should be the empty set. In Linz's example, we know that for all a^i there is a corresponding turin machine. Then he goes on to say there is a set for which there are strings that don't have corresponding machines. How does this count as proving that there are strings not in the language if all we did is just use a contradiction to deduce a contradiction?

I tried to make my question as clear as I can, let me know if something need clarification.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The phrase "there exists a complement of an RE language is not RE" shows that you might be confused about complements. *Every* language has *the* complement, simply because every subset has a unique complement. You should have said "there exists an RE language whose complement is not RE". One does not have to justify the existence of a complement, that's just part of foundations of mathematics.
2. It is false that the author defines $L$ using the condition "for all $i > 0$, $a^i \in L(M_i)$. The correct condition is that $a^i \in L$ *if and only if* $a^i \in L(M_i)$. In other words, we have
   $$L = \{a^i \mid a^i \in L(M_i) \}.$$
   For instance, whether $42 \in L$ depends on what the $42$-nd Turing machine $M_{42}$ does: if it accepts 42 then $42 \in L$, otherwise $42 \not\in L$.
3. A language may be *any* subset of the set $\Sigma^{*}$ of all words (over a given alphabet). It does not matter whether there is a Turing machine that accepts it. If there is one, that's a special kind of language. Anyhow, if you accept that $L$ is well-defined subset of $\Sigma^{*}$, then you have to accept that its complement is also a subset of $\Sigma^{*}$, therefore a language. It just so happens that this language is not recognized by any Turing machine. In fact, that is what the gist of the argument in the book is about.

Comment: I think I understand it better now but still having some problems. What is the point of making a correspondence between a^i and the i-th machine, why wouldn't it work just with any turing machine?

I'm still not getting the complement thing. I understand that every language is a subset of the set Σ*, but aren't we defining a language that enumerates every possible a? if so, then the complement of that language has to be the empty set. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: You misunderstand the definition of $L$. It is *not* the language of all $a^i$. Answer this: is $42$ an element of $L$? You should convince yourself that in order to answer this, you need to understand what $M_{42}$ does.

Comment: Ok I'll try to answer. If 42 is an element of L, then M42 generates the specific string with 42 a's. L accepts that along with other strings that are enumerated by that specific machine (M42). Does that sound right?

Comment: No. $M_{42}$ does not *generate* strings, it either *accepts* or *rejects* them. If $M_{42}$ accepts `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` then $a^{42} \in L$. If it rejects it then $a^{42} \not\in L$. We do not know which is the case unless we actually look at this $M_{42}$ machine and run it with input `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`.

Comment: Ok M42 accepts the string with 42 a's. But it does accept other strings right? Or is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" the only string it accepts?

Comment: I think I get it now. So every turing machine (Mi) accepts a recursively enumerable language that is infinite, if a^i is an accepted string in the machine Mi, then it is in L. Now if we consider the complement of L to be RE then we'll get a paradox. That proves that our assumption that L is RE is false. I hope I'm getting this right!

Comment: We don't know what $M_{42}$ does because we never agreed in what particular order we wish to enumerate Turing machines. The enumeration $M_1, M_2, ...$  has not been specified. It exists, and the proof works for any such acceptable enumeration. Because it is very painful to give the details of one the author has not bothered to give it. But you should understand what it takes to give an enumeration of all Turing machines.  And you should understand that it does not matter which enumeration we use as the proof works for any one.

Comment: You're right except in your claim that every $M_i$ accepts an infinite language. Some accept finite languages.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, for some reason I thought that Ms were ordered in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

$M_i$ is the $i^{th}$ machine in the enumeration of all Turing machines whose alphabet is $\{a\}$. $L(M_i)$ is the language recognized by that Turing machine.

The set $L$ is the set of all strings $a^i$ (i.e. strings whose alphabet is $\{a\}$ such that the string is recognized  by the $i^{th}$ Turing machine in the enumeration. So its complement includes a string $a^i$ if it is *not* recognized by the Turing machine $M_i$. That certainly does not involve a paradox; it is a simple statement of fact.

You seem to be reading $a^i \notin L(M_i)$ as though it were the complement of $\exists j ( a^i \in L(M_j))$. It is not. It is simply a statement about a single value of $i$.

Comment: So Mi is a machine that enumerates strings that includes a^i. A complement of the language of that machine is language which does not have a^i. Did I get this right?

Comment: @mathstudent: it doesn't matter what other strings $M_i$ might or might not accept, and the complement of the language of $M_i$ is also irrelevant. The string $a^i$ is in $L$ if and only if it is recognized by $M_i$. Therefore it is in $L'$ if and only if it is *not* recognized by $M_i$. That is the definition of $L$, nothing more.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks for the clarification.